# Xamarin Sport App - What does IsDirty do?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I am looking through the Xamarin Sport app code and trying to understand some of the cool things they are doing in it. I cannot understand what `IsDirty` is being used for exactly. It gets defined [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/master/Sport.Shared/BaseNotify.cs#L47) and implemented [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Shared/Models/BaseModel.cs#L52) and used in many places, such as [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Shared/ViewModels/AuthenticationViewModel.cs#L130).

I read a little about and `ICommand`'s `IsDirty` property so maybe it is a way to call an entire model as being dirty, but what implications does that have?

I also see it being used [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Shared/BaseNotify.cs#L69) which I am assuming is why they created it in the first place.

Thanks for y'all's insight into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just using it as a clever way to handle modification detection. Consider a "Save Changes" feature; you don't actually want to enable the "Save" button until something has changed, and you can key off the IsDirty property to test that.

Technically, you could handle this yourself by having a base class hook [INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and maintaining a dirty bit of your own (possibly in a base class), but rather than require all of their classes to have an `IsDirty` property that they may or may not need, they've made it an optional feature that a class *can* implement. For example, take a look at [GameResult](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Shared/Models/GameResult.cs) for an example of something that can't be changed, and therefore, can't be marked as dirty.

With this approach, you've minimized the amount of code you need to write to implement this functionality. All your derived classes need to do is derive from `BaseNotify`, implement `IDirty`, and call `SetPropertyChanged(...)` as the setter to set the private tracking field, signal to any observers that a property has changed, and automatically set the dirty bit.

NOTE: I did just make an interesting observation: while the implementation of the `SetProperty` extension method does set the `IsDirty` flag, the `BaseNotify` class' `IsDirty` implementation doesn't call anything to bubble up a `PropertyChanged` event for `IsDirty`, which means bindings against it won't get updated when it changes. I believe the fix would be for that extension method to invoke `PropertyChanged` with the property name "IsDirty":

```
if(dirty != null) {
    dirty.IsDirty = true;
    handler.Invoke(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsDirty"));
    // Yes, I'm a bad person for hard-coding the name.
}
```

Alternately, you could defer signaling the `IsDirty` change until after you signal the original property has changed. I just chose to keep it with the original logic.

Comment: Very cool. Really appreciate your answer and the fix! Am going to try and try it out now that I know what it can be used for.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's relatively simple and you're on the right track: the purpose of that property is to have an easy way to know whether *some* property has been changed, so the whole object has to be saved. It's baked in to the way property changes are propagated, so you don't have to set it by yourself whenever a property value is being set.

tl;dr: You can use it to check if you your (view)model is worth a save operation ,-).